# Does anything like Apex exist for other databases?

Tags: oracle-apex

I used Apex just a bit years ago. Apex fills me with admiration, it effectively reduces the complexity of publishing data to the web. I'm very good with relational databases but never took to Oracle, and that's part of why I didn't stick with Apex.
For all of these years I've been hoping that something like Apex would show up that would work with sql server, or postgresql. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: As far as I know, APEX is still unique. Other low/no-code products are out there, but they aren't free or integrated with the underlying database in the same way.

Comment: I've never seen one either, and I do look for them. I wouldn't particularly want the framework to be tied directly to the db backend, as Apex is. There were some good efforts in the past but the ones that I'm aware of faded out .

Comment: Appian and PegaSystems are out there and kind of do for Java what APEX did for PL/SQL, but they aren't free and have some specific design challenges (like storing all app data in a single BLOB column). They also don't scale automatically with the database the way APEX does, do HA as well, etc.